# Emails backup from cpanel

Tags: email, cpanel

can someone please tell me how i can backup emails from cpanel without having to backup the full site? Thanks for answering

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Aren't they just files in /mail/[email-addr] ?

So just download them using an FTP client.

Comment: The real catch is, can you restore the account by uploading it over FTP to a different hosting? (lets assume they have the same domain in both old and new cpanel)

Answer (score 0):

You can not backup your emails using ftp. If you want to backup your mails then you have to download the mails using pop3. There is no other way you can download your mails.

Comment: Actually you are incorrect, as the email has to reside somewhere on the server, and on my webserver they are as files under a mail folder / mailbox name. Although I have disallowed FTP any access to the folder, I could setup FTP if I so wanted.

Comment: @Skuld yes the emails are stored in a folder in the server but to access that folder you should have the root access not in the case of user login and especially in a shared server hosting.

Comment: @Ampre Depends on the setup of the server, shared server hosting is always different (and often locked down) compared to having one on your own (like mine)

Comment: @Skuld exactly. Thanks for your comments. I could have mentioned it as in the case of shared hosting. a

Answer (score 0):

You can download the mails using command line or FTP. Or simple way is, configure the email account in mail client, download the all emails on your local system.

Else you can download the emails by configuring them using POP3.

Most of the time, only emails can't be restored so best is to configure the email account and download them.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach to download the email is to configure it in a email client, and then taking a backup of the same.

Eg:
configure the email in your outlook, and then download a backup of the same in a pst format.

now you can restore the same via outlook by importing the pst file.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Email Backup Wizard tool , Best Solution so far , Run the tool Select IMAP , export in any format , https://emailbackupwizard.com/